# Does an interrupt handler have a timeout?

Tags: c, interrupt, interrupt-handling, isr

Testing a code that uses interrupts, I forced with a `while(1);` to try to remain in the interrupt handler, but I saw that the interrupt handler leaves and returns to main, so I assume it has some kind of timeout. If so, is it particular to the ISR, or it is a standard feature of interrupts?

Comment: Please post the smallest reproducible example, ex. sample code including all the relevant `#include`s and `signal()` calls and including the `main()` function. Also post sample script including all relevant command, ex.  `kill -s what signal what pid`. All needed to reproduce the problem you are having. As a side note: what is `TRUE`?

Comment: What do you mean with "the program just exits"?

Comment: I found difficult to post a working sample code to show what I want, so I preferred to post it like something theoretical. With "the program just exits" i meant that the interrupt handler exits and returns to main function. I'll rewrite it, sorry for that.

Comment: No, the interrupt handler does not exit if you have written `while(1);` inside it.

Comment: @kamil-cuk with "while(TRUE)" I meant a loop where it should not exit to see its behaviour towards functions that may require some processing time being called from the interrupt handler. I rewrote it to "while(1)"

Comment: @Lundin but I saw that it was not staying in `while(1)`, so could it be related to a kind of watchdog that makes it leave the handler?

Comment: @EUS This may be a better question for https://programmers.stackexchange.com just a heads up. But the answer to this really depends on the OS. Most modern OSes don't allow drivers to directly handle interrupts themselves instead using a queue and message system to service them relatively real time. They do this to prevent drivers from hijacking the system by disabling interrupts. As your question is written we really can't answer it.

Comment: Normally debuggers can't cope with watchdog resets. Those who can will show your program restarting from reset, not returning to the point where the interrupt occurred. You are doing something wrong and we cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @Mgetz What makes you think there is an OS? And in general, programming questions are not welcome at programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a standard feature of interrupts.  You don't say what platform you are using, but in general, interrupt handlers should do only what is necessary, and return.  The less time spent in the handler, the better.

It is possible your program has a watchdog timer somewhere, and when starved for processing time (because the ISR hung), the timer fires and is designed to exit your program.